# How to execute Google Play Location Samples from github

Tags: android, google-play-services

I managed to build the sub project BasicLocationSample from https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location. But as soon as I try to run either in Emulator or in Samsung Galaxy S 2. It immediately crash. I tried to check any reasonable clue in logcat but nothing significant to mention. I tried to set breakpoint at Main Activity's onCreate very first line. It doesn't even call it :( .

I can run ActivityRecognition and LocationAddress sample from the same sample list. So I must be missing something from BasicLocationSample. Please inform me how to run BasicLocationSample? Thanks in advance!

Comment: if there is a crash there is going to be a stacktrace of it, without that we cannot help you

Comment: I'm not sure is it a crash or not. Anyway here is the whole logcat output link: http://pastebin.com/WFMNK9LZ

Comment: It's a huge log. So I have to use a link from pastebin. Hope it's ok

Comment: That log seems to be nothing but system "noise". Nothing in that log appears to be from an app that you would have made. Please try to put `Log.e("@@@", "++ onCreate");` as the very first line in your onCreate right after the super function, set the LogCat to filter all messages with the error level and see if it prints anything.

Comment: The only reason why I think this might happen is that your manifest file is incorrect so that the app doesn't know which Activity to start at the app launch